# How To Get Multiple Outputs to Show From a For Loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have a for loop to get multiple outputs from an array. The `currencyType[type]` is used to pre-pend the proper letters to match the DIV ID in the HTML.

```
for(let type = 0; type <= currencyType.length; type++) {
    // This grabs the number from XRPUSDVAL + XRPUSDAMT                        
    let node = document.getElementById(currencyType[type].innerHTML+"USDVAL").textContent * document.getElementById(currencyType[type].innerHTML+"USDAMT").value;
    let total = node.toFixed(2);
    console.log(total)
}
```

I get 2 values of the `total` inside my console with the statement above that are dynamic numbers.

```
65704.50
99.91
```

However when I add a statement to try to output it to a `DIV ID` on my HTML, The console then only shows the result of 1 of the outputs

```
for(let type = 0; type <= currencyType.length; type++) {
    // This grabs the number from XRPUSDVAL + XRPUSDAMT                        
    let node = document.getElementById(currencyType[type].innerHTML+"USDVAL").textContent * document.getElementById(currencyType[type].innerHTML+"USDAMT").value;
    let total = node.toFixed(2);
    console.log(total)
    document.getElementById(currencyType[type]+"USDTOTAL").innerHTML = total; // <------ Added This Statement
}
```

Here is the section of the HTML as well where the Javascript interacts with

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 pbf-crypto-container">
            <form method="POST" action="/users/currencies/68">
                <h3 class="pbfCurrencyType">ETH</h3>
                <input class="form-control-lg" id="ETHUSDAMT" name="amount" type="text" value="75">
                <h3>Market Value: ($)</h3>
                <div id="ETHUSDVAL"></div>
                <h3>Total Value: ($)</h3>
                <div id="ETHUSDTOTAL"></div>
                <hr>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" id="pbf-update" type="submit" value="Update">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="pbf-refresh">Refresh</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 pbf-crypto-container">
            <form method="POST" action="/users/currencies/60">
                <h3 class="pbfCurrencyType">XRP</h3>
                <input class="form-control-lg" id="XRPUSDAMT" name="amount" type="text" value="100">
                <h3>Market Value: ($)</h3>
                <div id="XRPUSDVAL"></div>
                <h3>Total Value: ($)</h3>
                <div id="XRPUSDTOTAL"></div>
                <hr>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" id="pbf-update" type="submit" value="Update">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="pbf-refresh">Refresh</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was wondering if someone can show me the proper way so that within my for loop it will be able to insert the `total`'s into the section of my DIV that I specified. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are replacing the innerHTML in every loop, Please append instead of replacing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line seems to be wrong

```
document.getElementById(currencyType[type]+"USDTOTAL").innerHTML = total;
```

You need to **append `USDTOTAL` to `currencyType[type].innerHTML`** like earlier in the same loop.

Make it

```
document.getElementById(currencyType[type].innerHTML +"USDTOTAL").innerHTML = total;
```

Or refactor the code

```
for(let type = 0; type <= currencyType.length; type++) 
{
    let prefix = currencyType[type].innerHTML ;
    let node = document.getElementById( prefix +"USDVAL").textContent * document.getElementById( prefix +"USDAMT").value;
    let total = node.toFixed(2);
    console.log(total)
    document.getElementById( prefix + "USDTOTAL").innerHTML = total;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @gurvinder372, This solution worked and it is behaving like I wanted it to. I will accept the answer when it allows me to!

Answer (score 1):

try to append the results:

```
for(let type = 0; type <= currencyType.length; type++) {
    // This grabs the number from XRPUSDVAL + XRPUSDAMT                        
    let node = document.getElementById(currencyType[type].innerHTML+"USDVAL").textContent * document.getElementById(currencyType[type].innerHTML+"USDAMT").value;
    let total = node.toFixed(2);
    console.log(total)
    document.getElementById(currencyType[type]+"USDTOTAL").innerHTML += total; // <------ Added This Statement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can improve a lite bit more you code

**from here:**

```
for(let type = 0; type <= currencyType.length; type++) 
{
  let prefix = currencyType[type].innerHTML ;
  let node = document.getElementById( prefix +"USDVAL").textContent * document.getElementById( prefix +"USDAMT").value;
  let total = node.toFixed(2);
  console.log(total)
  document.getElementById( prefix + "USDTOTAL").innerHTML = total;
}
```

**to here:**

```
currencyType.forEach(currency => {
 const prefix = currency.innerHTML;
 const node = document.getElementById(`${prefix}USDVAL`).textContent * document.getElementById(`${prefix}USDAMT`).value;
 const total = node.toFixed(2);
 document.getElementById(`${prefix}USDTOTAL`).innerHTML = total;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, I was able to clean up the code with your suggestion. The only thing I had to do since I am working with an HTML collection was change the beginning to "Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('pbfCurrencyType')).forEach..." and everything is working as before but with a better syntax.